# Processing OCO2 netCDF data with python

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv, netcdf

**Update: I managed to extract XCO2 and average it monthly. Still, I need to find a solution to clip it on my specific shape as for now I am using a box defined by latitude and longitude around the region of interest.**

I am trying to process some (150gb) downloaded netCDF world OCO2 data but having issues with the code.

The goal is to **clip** the OCO2 netCDF files **for a specified region (shapefile), **filter**  for the xco2 quality flag (binary filtering this variable for '0'), extract only xco2 as a variable and average each file daily**, combining them so that I can **calculate a monthly average** and if possible **export these as csv files**.

This is a lot to do, and I am already happy that I managed to batchdownload the files correctly. They are all stored in one folder with the following filename structure:

oco2_LtCO2_yymmdd_Bbuild id_production date.nc4

Example: oco2_LtCO2_220902_B11100Ar_230609082428s.nc4

I would be very happy if anyone has experience with processing this data.

I already tried using various online tutorials to clip the netCDF file to a shapefile, unfortunately without luck. I partly get errors for libraries or simply don't understand the code of others.

This is a jupyter notebook (python) code I use to calculate and plot the monthly mean of one file:

```
# OCO-2 XCO2 Data Analysis

%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline

import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn-v0_8")
import csv
import numpy as np
import os
import os.path
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import HTML
from IPython.display import clear_output
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
from oco_tools import *
import xarray as xr

file_dict = dict_oco2_xco2

# which dataset
path_files = 'FilepathXYZ'

# Load the netCDF file
f = xr.open_dataset('File.nc4')

# set bounding box
latMin = 44
latMax = 47
lonMin = -76
lonMax = -71

oco2_aoi = OCO2(path_files+'/*.nc4', file_dict, latMin, latMax, lonMin, lonMax)

t_unit_oco2 = "seconds since 1970-1-1 0:0:0"
t_cal = u"gregorian"

# Convert oco2 time units to a python time
oco2_aoi.time_python  = convert_time(oco2_aoi.time, t_unit_oco2, t_cal)
oco2_aoi.time_str = [datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(str(date)) for date in oco2_aoi.time_python]

# oco2_aoi.time[0] # seconds since 1970
# oco2_aoi.time_python[0].strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
# oco2_aoi.time_str[0]

## Timeseries

##  Running average timeseries
from datetime import datetime
dates = np.arange('2022-09', '2023-02', dtype='datetime64[3D]').astype(datetime)

len(dates)

# Calculating running mean (30 days)
timeseries_oco2 = running_mean(oco2_aoi.time_str, oco2_aoi.xco2, dates, 30)

# exporting a string variable into the csv file
input_variable = timeseries_oco2.mean
 
# Example.csv gets created in the current working directory
with open('Example.csv', 'w', newline = '') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['xco2']
    my_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter = ';')
    
    my_writer.writeheader()
    my_writer.writerow(input_variable)
```

Unfortunately, the csv export does not work and I am not able to clip my file onto the dedicated area of interest (shapefile). Additionally, I have to filter for the quality flag (0) and iterate the whole process for the rest of the files within the folder.

Clipping and filtering for variables at first would be desirable since it would lower the filesize significantly.

I am thankful for any leads and suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a lot going on in this question. Consider making it more focused. and also, consider making the code example reproducible. You have provided us with a bunch of code that is irrelevant to the question. Why are you showing plotting code, print statements, commented out code and lines calculating length of variables? Make life easy for us

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited the code accordingly. I hope my question is more clear now!